# excessive garbage collector in android for AsyncTask

Tags: android, performance, logging, memory-management

i am trying to download json object using URL, for that i have created one AsyncTask. Whenever i am starting my application, excessive garbage collector starts. i cant understad where i am going wrong.i am not performing any heavy memory usage task just trying to call api for json response.

**MainActivity Code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result=null;
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=null;

        try {
            url= new URL(urls[0]);
            httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream= httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader= new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int data= inputStreamReader.read();
            while(data !=1){
                char current= (char) data;
                result +=current;
                data= inputStreamReader.read();
            }
            return result;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("webssite Content :",result);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DownloadTask downloadTask= new DownloadTask();
    downloadTask.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=5868b18238384fb4bdb3123jn9f0847cc");
}}
```

**Logcat**

```
06-19 08:45:57.149 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 4438K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.149 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.091MB for 720030-byte allocation
06-19 08:45:57.149 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 24% free 4672K/6144K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
06-19 08:45:57.159 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1172K, 36% free 3969K/6144K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
06-19 08:45:57.159 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 4438K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.159 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.091MB for 720034-byte allocation
06-19 08:45:57.159 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 24% free 4672K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.169 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1172K, 36% free 3969K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.169 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 4438K/6144K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-19 08:45:57.169 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.091MB for 720036-byte allocation
06-19 08:45:57.179 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 24% free 4672K/6144K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
06-19 08:45:57.179 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1172K, 36% free 3969K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.189 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 4438K/6144K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
06-19 08:45:57.189 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.091MB for 720040-byte allocation
06-19 08:45:57.189 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 24% free 4672K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.199 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1172K, 36% free 3969K/6144K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-19 08:45:57.199 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 4438K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.199 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.091MB for 720042-byte allocation
06-19 08:45:57.199 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 24% free 4672K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.209 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1172K, 36% free 3969K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.219 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 4438K/6144K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
06-19 08:45:57.219 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.091MB for 720046-byte allocation
06-19 08:45:57.229 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 24% free 4672K/6144K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
06-19 08:45:57.229 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1172K, 36% free 3969K/6144K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-19 08:45:57.239 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 4438K/6144K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
06-19 08:45:57.239 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.091MB for 720048-byte allocation
06-19 08:45:57.239 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 24% free 4672K/6144K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
06-19 08:45:57.249 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1172K, 36% free 3969K/6144K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
06-19 08:45:57.249 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 4438K/6144K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
06-19 08:45:57.249 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.091MB for 720052-byte allocation
06-19 08:45:57.259 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 24% free 4672K/6144K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
06-19 08:45:57.259 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1172K, 36% free 3969K/6144K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
06-19 08:45:57.269 6269-6283/com.hemkar.jsondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 28% free 4438K/6144K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
06-19 0
```

Comment: Have you try with a real device or only with the virtual one?

Comment: I have tried with emulator, you mean it may work fine in real device ?

Answer (score 3):

I think because in your code  **while(data !=1)**, correct should be  **while(data !=-1)**. The loop is infinite

Comment: I agree,  if the end of the stream is reached read() return -1.